# MySQL query to get latest unique chat conversation

Tags: mysql

Following is my tables structure for chat messages and Users.

I want latest 1 message from all conversations to/from a user e.g. User2

```
ChatMsgs
========
+--------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| ChatID | FKFromUID |  FKToUID |  Message  |
+--------+-----------+----------+-----------+
|      1 |         3 |        2 |    Hello1 |
|      2 |         2 |        1 |    Hello2 |
|      3 |         2 |        3 |    Hello3 |
|      4 |         3 |        2 |    Hi1    |
|      5 |         2 |        3 |    Hi2    |
|      6 |         3 |        2 |    Hi3    |
+--------+-----------+----------+-----------+

Users
======
+--------+----------+
| UserID | Fullname |
+--------+----------+
|      1 |    User1 |
|      2 |    User2 |
|      3 |    User3 |
+--------+----------+
```

I want the result as following filtered for specific user, e.g. User2

```
+--------+----------+---------+
| UserID | Fullname | Message |
+--------+----------+---------+
|      3 |  User3   | Hi3     |
|      1 |  User1   | Hello2  |
+--------+----------+---------+
```

As you can see in result set none of info/column for the User2 but for other users but only those records where User2 exist either in FKFromUID or FKToUID.

Here's the query I created but it gives extra records if user exit it both From and To.

```
select U.UserID
     , FullName
     , Message 
  from ChatMsgs C 
  JOIN 
     ( select max(ChatID) chatID 
         from ChatMsgs 
        group 
           by FKToUID
         , FKFromUID
     ) CC 
    ON C.ChatID = CC.ChatID 
  JOIN Users U 
    ON U.UID = C.FKFromUID 
 where C.FKToUID = 2 
union 
select U.UserID, FullName, Message from ChatMsgs C JOIN (select max(ChatID) chatID from ChatMsgs group 
    by FKToUID, FKFromUID) CC ON C.ChatID=CC.ChatID JOIN Users U ON U.UID=C.FKToUID where C.FKFromUID=2
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What are you having trouble with?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select U.UserID, FullName, Message, C.CreationTime ChatTime from UserChats C JOIN (select max(UserChatID) chatID from UserChats group by FKToUserID, FKFromUserID) CC ON C.UserChatID=CC.ChatID JOIN Users U ON U.UserID=C.FKFromUserID where C.FKToUserID=@userID 
UNION 
select U.UserID, FullName, Message, C.CreationTime ChatTime from UserChats C JOIN (select max(UserChatID) chatID from UserChats group by FKFromUserID, FKToUserID) CC ON C.UserChatID=CC.ChatID JOIN Users U ON U.UserID=C.FKToUserID where C.FKFromUserID=@userID
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you just need to select the `ChatMsgs` that you want (e.g. `FKToUID = 2`) and join with `Users`.

```
SELECT Users.UserID, Users.Fullname, ChatMsgs.Message
  FROM ChatMsgs
  INNER JOIN Users ON ChatMsgs.FKFromUID = Users.UserID
 WHERE ChatMsgs.FKToUID = 2
```

Comment: This would return 3 records. user only want's latest message of each chat.  Note that 3,2 were chatting and 2,1 were chatting.

Comment: I was expecting something like that but I wasn't able to reverse-engineer that requirement from the desired result.

Comment: Your suggested query doesn't provide the required result.
It returns multiple rows for a user with other user while requirement is to return only one latest row.

Answer (score 0):

For  User 2 you could obtain the max id for the related  chat and the join with users

```
  select User.UserID, Users.Fullname, t.Message
  from ( 
    select case when FKFromUID = 2 then FKToUID else FKFromUID 
            END as UserID 
    from ChatMsgs
    where id in (
   select max(id)
   from ChatMsgs where  FKFromUIDFromUID  = 2
   union 
   select max(id)
   from ChatMsgs where  FKToUID  = 2
   ) )  t 
   inner join users on t.UserID = Userse .UserID
```

Comment: This query not running, it gives syntax error near "as UserID" in 3rd line.

Answer (score 0):

I keep thinking there has to be an easier way...  but this appears to work.

DEMO:
http://rextester.com/MUMAVP47179

```
SELECT U.userID, U.FullName, Cm.Message
FROM (SELECT MAX(Z.ChatID) chatID, UID
      FROM (SELECT ChatID, case when FKFROMUID = 2 then FKTOUID else FKFROMUID end as UID 
            FROM ChatMsgs) Z
      GROUP BY UID) Y
INNER JOIN Users U
 on U.userID = Y.UID
INNER JOIN ChatMsgs CM
 on Cm.ChatID = Y.ChatID 
ORDER BY Y.chatID desc;
```